# Not able to access Pentaho with same user at different places

Tags: authentication, pentaho, pentaho-cde

We're using Pentaho BA 7.0 (community edition)

Accessing CDE dashboard output by adding login credentials into the URL. Like,

http://localhost:8080/pentaho/app?userid=abcd&password=xxxx&locale=en_US

(In the production, the server has SSL)

Showing dashboard fine at the one place. At the same time, If I'm accessing from another one browser or another one system, Getting the below error as "Sorry, something went wrong."

[Screenshot-IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHNX7.png)

But, Multiple login access working fine with **Admin** user, not with any other newly created users.

Comment: So what is the problem here ? Access problem or new user credential problem ?

Comment: @WorkingHard..  Problem is multiple access.